# Cannot assign value of type String to type AnyObject? Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am suddenly getting this error for a dictionary of type:

```
var parameters = [String: AnyObject]()
```

and then if I try:

```
parameters["cancelled_by"] = someUser ?? ""
```

I am getting the error as :

> Cannot assign value of type String to type AnyObject?

This is for `Swift 3.0`. What am I doing wrong here? Why doesn't it work?

Comment: how is `someUser ` defined?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`String` is the **value type**. `AnyObject` only accepts **reference types**. So in order to add both value types and reference types in `Dictionary` use `Any` instead of `AnyObject`, i.e.

```
var parameters = [String: Any]()
```

This is an addition to Swift 3.0.

Answer (score 1):

I'm starting with Swift 3 right now, a bit late... however, until Swift 2.2 some Swift value types were automatically bridged to the corresponding foundation reference types, such as `String` to `NSString`, `Dictionary<>` to `NSDictionary`, and so forth. It looks like this automatic bridging has been removed in Swift 3.

There are cases where turning a `[String : AnyObject]` into `[String : Any]` makes sense, in others it doesn't, depending on what you're doing. In my current case, where I need reference types, it doesn't.

So I am solving the problem by requesting an explicit bridging, by casting to `AnyObject`:

```
var dictionary: [String : AnyObject] = [:]
dictionary["valueType"] = "Value Type" // Error
dictionary["referenceType"] = "Reference Type" as AnyObject // OK
```

For reference:

```
let text = "Text"
let asAny = text as Any
let asAnyObject = text as AnyObject
let asNSString: NSString = text as NSString

type(of: text) // Prints String.Type
type(of: asAny) // Prints String.Type
type(of: asAnyObject) // Prints _NSContiguousString.Type
type(of: asNSString) // Prints _NSContiguousString.Type
```